# read/disp file content by using prefix

Tags: matlab

Is there a way to read and print the content of a file on which I don't know the fullname
example:

```
myFile = fullfile(systemPath,'aeroD_*.txt')
% fileread ,textread doesn't work as the filename isn't complete
```

how to read/print the content of the file?

Answer (score 1):

use `dir` to get all possible file names with wildchars and then print each file

```
fls = dir( fullfile(systemPath,'aeroD_*.txt') );
for fi=1:numel( fls )
     myFile = fullfile( systemPath, fls(fi).name ); % now name has no wildchars
     % ... read the file
end
```